# User prompted to select a file to be imported

Tags: excel, vba, import, getfiles

First time caller, long time listener.

I am trying to create a vba function to import a .csv file of the users choice into a specific sheet using the comma as the only delimiter.

From the macro I recorded. I'd like to change the part where a specific file is chose to

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;Y:\CDM\FromOptum\Salesforce\Campaigns\AddCampaign_106_CNSOH_MMP_2018032812040.csv" _
    , Destination:=Range("$B$10"))
    .Name = "AddCampaign_106_CNSOH_MMP_2018032812040_6"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know how to declare and assign a variable?

Comment: I do not, that sounds rather useful though.

Comment: `Dim path As String` declares a string variable, named `path`. Then you can prompt for a file name, say, `path = Application.GetOpenFileName` - and now that `path` has the value, you can concatenate it into your connection string, e.g. `Connection:="TEXT;" & path`. This is fairly basic stuff you can find literally everywhere on this site - good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I am new, bet you couldn't tell :)